# Duvida sobre fechamento do $ionicLoading.hide()

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Meu problema é o seguinte. Estou recebendo um json de um webservice e fazendo insert ou update em um banco sqlite no dispositivo uso o $ionicLoading.show() ao clicar no botão e o mesmo fecha quando acaba a requisição com o servidor. Só que devido ser muitos dados o processamento no banco continua e eu queria fechar o loading somente quando acabar o processamento de dados no banco. Alguém teria alguma ideia do que fazer ?

Comment: O webservice está retornando antes de terminar as operações no banco? Você teria como alterá-lo?

Comment: Não o webservice esta normal. Inicio o loading.show() faço a requisição pelo $http.get depois que recebo todo o json do webservice ele fecha o $loading pra depois começar a fazer as operações com o banco. Gostaria que o $loading só se fechasse depois que terminasse as operações com o banco.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia chamar o dismiss() do loading apenas no retorno da chamada do serviço?

Por exemplo:

```
 let loading = this.loadingController.create({
        content : "Loading..."
    });

loading.present();
```

service.getServico(items => {
          loading.dismiss();
        }
  });